# why malloc always return a address of 0x???????8

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I write a simple code:-

```
 void * aa = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
 printf("%X\n", aa);
 free(aa);
```

It always prints ???????8,
What I want to ask is:
Does malloc always return a 4*n address?
And why here the last number of the address always is 8? why not 4 or C?
my environment:
ubuntu 10.04 (32 bit)
gcc version 4.4.3

Comment: The printf should be `printf("%p\n", aa);`. And `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1.

Comment: Why do you `free(aa)` before `malloc`? Also, sizeof(char) always returns 1 byte.

Comment: sorry for duplicate 2 lines of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reasons are generally rooted in [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) issues; the constraint is there to fulfill processor requirements, assist [cache optimization strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) or other reasons.

As part of the core purpose of satisfying system (OS, language specification, processor) alignment requirements which would otherwise result in either faults (with varying impacts depending on the system) or inefficient behavior (having to do extra memory reads to get the same data as it straddles a memory block boundary) at runtime, a minimum alignment requirement will apply.

However you may empirically find that they are aligned to an even higher degree than that strictly required by the preceding constraints. For example, a specific allocator implementation might increase it for reasons such as:

- adding memory overrun barriers and/or other integrity checking/verification mechanisms
- allow pointers to be stored more efficiently (e.g. if you know the bottom 4 bits are zero, you can potentially pack them in some manner when you persist them
- simplifying or increasing the efficiency of address computations
- reducing fragmentation and/or other reasons which may seem to make not offer a benefit for an individual alllocation but satisfy some goal across a larger set of allocations

Comment: Actually C *requires* the returned pointer to be suitably aligned for any type. On systems where there's a type that requires 8-byte alignment, the last nibble of the pointer must be either 0 or 8.

Comment: @R.. I was referring to the fact that, regardless of whether C, C++ or the environment actually requires it, an allocator may opt to increase the block size for any reason of its own it sees fit too (e.g., to reduce fragmentation, to allow pointers to be e.g. 4 bits less and enable those 4 bits to be used as flags). Tightening up language to include this.

Comment: @R.. I see now that at-aix got that point across more cleanly. You'll have to take my word for it that I was aware of that and was trying to get that point across when this answer first went up!

Comment: Sorry I think my comment came across as too critical. I didn't downvote or anything; I just thought it was unclear that `malloc` must do some alignment to meet the requirements, apart from optional additional alignment to meet its own implementation needs or performance goals.

Comment: @R.. Grando. I personally like at-aix's answer too hence my +1 on it - it does answer it precisely and succinctly (as opposed to my bad examples of why an allocator might opt to increase the alignment for its own reasons). (It was the ''only correct'' bit in the other comment that got me riled and typing :D)

Comment: The / in my comment on that answer was because I was undecided between whether it was "the most correct" or "the only correct" answer. :-)

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues at play:

1. `malloc()` is required to return an address that is aligned such that it can be used for any data type. More formally (C99 7.20.3):

   > The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).
2. The implementer of the allocator could choose to work with blocks of memory that are larger than the smallest block implied by the alignment requirements. This could be done, for example, for efficiency reasons (there are trade-offs involved).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is alignment, 8 byte alignment is what is deemed most efficient.

you can start here:  http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_31.html